# How to exclude a controller (e.g. Notifycontroller ) from devise's session timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Once session expire timeout is defined in `devise.rb`, it is available in entire rails application.  But I want to exclude it from some specific controller say `Notifycontroller` which sends notification in every 2 minutes and my session expiration timeout is define after 30 minutes in `devise.rb`.

I want to keep `notifycontroller` untouched from devise session expire timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because the client/user only has one session active at a time. So the client/user is either logged in or not, you cannot make exceptions for particular routes.

Comment: thank you for replying. Do you have any idea how we can achieve that. e.g. by writing customize session expire timeout or any thing else.

Comment: You have to say more about what you expect to happen exactly, how you expect it to work. You might want to read up more on the basics of how sesisons work, what they really are. For instance [here](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) or google for more on Rails sessions.   I think there may be some problems with how you expect your NotifyController to work, regardless of session timeouts, if you expect it to somehow be sending notifications to a particular user regularly, rather than as a result of a user visiting the page in their browser.

Comment: I am able to solve the issue. I created custom actions in application controller and called them before_action and excluded those method from notifycontroller for the method which was sending the notification in every 2 minutes. Below is the code

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is to continuously notify every 2 minutes even if the session of the user has timed out. I think you can move the notify action or the block of code doing the action in a model and you could use 'whenever' gem to run your block of code in the model every 2 minutes. The running of code will not be affected by the session of the user.

whenever gem: https://github.com/javan/whenever